# C++ how to prevent import loops

Tags: c++, class, include, header-files

I am a bit in the dark for the moment so I am trying stack overflow. My problem is that I have a classed named ‘Scene’ which will have a map of ‘GameObject’. The problem is that these GameObject need to use some function from there scene so I create a Scene* that is assigned to the main scene. The problem with this case is that I a in a loop where I import Scene which include GameObject which include Scene (and it goes on). If you think 5isnis not clear feel free to comment I will give more detail or edit this post thx.

Scene.h

```
class Scene
{
public:
    sf::RenderWindow* window;
    _Manager manager;

    sf::Color backgroundColor;
    std::string name;

    std::map<std::string, GameObject*> gameObjects;

    Scene();
    Scene(std::string name);

    virtual void Start() = 0;
    virtual void Update() = 0;
    virtual void Draw() = 0;

    void _Update();
};
```

GameObject.h

```
class GameObject : public Object
{
private:
    Scene* scene;
    std::vector<Component*> components;
public:
    Transform* transform = new Transform;

    void AddComponent(Component* component);
    Component* GetComponent(std::string type);

    GameObject* Find();
    void Instantiate(GameObject* gm, Transform* transform);

    void Start();
    void Update();
};
```

Comment: Hi interesting, perhaps split the common dependency into its own component, maybe using an interface?

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about header files, and recursive dependencies between them. What you need to do is open your C++ textbook to the chapter that explains what forward declarations are and how to use them, and then read that chapter. All will be explained.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Hi, I know a bit about those declarations but the problem is that I need to declare that class and I need to declare a void that will be defined later

Comment: Is your problem due to a lack of include guards or more directly resolving a [circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+circular+dependency)?

Comment: @JaMiT this post seems to have plenty of informations thanks

Comment: "I need to declare that class" and "I need to declare a void that will be defined later" are not useful problem descriptions. "Declare a void", what does that mean? Code speaks louder than words. We can only guess as to what you are trying to do. Please follow the rules for creating a [mre].

Comment: @Requin5 That is not an answer to my question. Your question is still unclear.

Comment: @JaMiT I added the code to my post, What I want to do is access the map of GameObject from the scene but how can I do this without circular dependency?

Comment: @Requin5 There's no need for `Scene` to know about the details/size of `GameObject` in the header beyond the fact that there's some class that exists called that and that you want to point to it given the code you posted. You can forward declare it with just `class GameObject` at the top of `Scene.h`. `GameObject` also doesn't need to know about the details of `Scene`. It can forward declare Scene. Both can avoid including each other's headers in their own headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who got the same problem i just forgot you can do forward declaration and when you need to use the full class just import the files you need in the .cpp file of your class.